# keras constraint doesn't get called

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Keras constraint docs: https://keras.io/constraints/. 
I used `NonNeg` constraint to keep some of my network dense layer weights positive, usage like :

```
layer1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, kernel_constraint=NonNeg())
```

But some of the layer weights is still negative, I viewed the source code of keras constraint: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/constraints.py#L62 , it's very straightforward. So I wonder if the constraint is not called. So I wrote a customed constraint which throw an exception directly as

```
class ConstraintDemo(Constraint):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("CONSTRAINT called")
    def __call__(self, w):
        raise RuntimeError("GLQ ERROR")
        logging.info("CONSTRAINT called")
        return tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(w, 0.), tf.float32)
```

And I called the class similarly by

```
layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, kernel_constraint=ConstraintDemo())
```

Only the **init** method get called.The **call** method should raise a RuntimeError and stop the training process. But it didn't.

Why?

tensorflow version: 1.12.0

keras version:2.0.6

Comment: Please include the full model that includes this layer

Comment: Also please check that this reproduces in tf nightly and in tf.keras